# Inconsistent ddply multiple quantiles by group

Tags: r, plyr, quantile, summarize

I am trying to use ddply to summarize median and 25th/75th precentiles of multiple groups in a relatively small data set.  I am grouping by DoseWt the measured datapoints AUC_INFobs and Cmax. (Using R 4.0.4 in RStudio 1.3.1093 on Windows 10)
Although the results for AUCINF_obs agree whether calculated by line (for DoseWt==0.3) vs ddply & summarize, that is not the case with my data for Cmax:

```
median(NCAtrim$Cmax[NCAtrim$DoseWt==0.3])
quantile(NCAtrim$Cmax[NCAtrim$DoseWt==0.3], 0.25)
quantile(NCAtrim$Cmax[NCAtrim$DoseWt==0.3], 0.75)

NCA.by.Dose.25_75tile<-ddply(NCAtrim, .(DoseWt), summarize,
   AUC_inf = round(median(AUCINF_obs),2), AUCinf25 = round(quantile(AUCINF_obs, 0.25),2), AUCinf75 = round(quantile(AUCINF_obs, 0.75),2),
     Cmax = round(median(Cmax), 2), Cmax_25 = round(quantile(Cmax, 0.25), 2), Cmax_75 = round(quantile(Cmax, 0.75), 2))    
NCA.by.Dose.25_75tile
```

Can anyone explain why I am not able to generate the 25th and 75th percentiles with ddply summarize for Cmax here, but the 25th, 50th, and 75th percentiles AUCINF_obs work? (I also tried quantile(Cmax, probs =0.25).

```
NCAtrim <- structure(list(Subject = c(103L, 103L, 103L, 105L, 105L, 107L, 
107L, 107L, 109L, 111L, 111L, 111L, 113L, 113L, 113L, 114L, 114L, 
114L, 117L, 117L, 117L, 124L, 124L, 124L, 126L, 126L, 126L, 127L, 
127L, 127L, 130L, 130L, 130L), DoseWt = c(0.3, 0.45, 0.6, 0.3, 
0.45, 0.3, 0.45, 0.6, 0.3, 0.3, 0.45, 0.6, 0.3, 0.45, 0.6, 0.3, 
0.45, 0.6, 0.3, 0.45, 0.6, 0.3, 0.45, 0.6, 0.3, 0.45, 0.6, 0.3, 
0.45, 0.6, 0.3, 0.45, 0.6), AUCINF_obs = c(75.57957417, 104.7376298, 
193.1863023, 150.8553768, 231.6657641, 97.55371159, 153.2804929, 
213.179011, 90.84944244, 54.65739998, 93.3108462, 78.07527241, 
61.31713576, 89.91275385, 126.6723822, 94.02414615, 166.3379068, 
227.4162735, 98.84793101, 172.1750658, 149.2339892, 79.45304645, 
142.0389319, 171.7761067, 44.36951602, 86.64275743, 107.4389943, 
56.42917332, 112.4691754, 144.4193233, 87.22135293, 137.3190569, 
151.0853702), Cmax = c(17.2, 22.7, 54.1, 16, 43.3, 19.8, 35.1, 
48, 30.6, 12.4, 18.2, 16.4, 16, 27.8, 31.3, 14.5, 24.6, 37.6, 
15.3, 26, 27.7, 16.5, 24.3, 19.7, 11, 15.8, 43.2, 14.6, 29.8, 
35.6, 19, 38.1, 39)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-33L))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is because the value of `Cmax` is changed when you run `Cmax = round(median(Cmax), 2)`. The next command that you run (`Cmax_25 = round(quantile(Cmax, 0.25), 2)`) gets this changed `Cmax` value and not the original one.

You can keep that line at the last so that it will not change the `Cmax` value. Also `plyr` is retired so you may want to switch to `dplyr`.

```
library(dplyr)

NCAtrim %>%
  group_by(DoseWt) %>%
  summarise(AUC_inf = round(median(AUCINF_obs),2), 
            AUCinf25 = round(quantile(AUCINF_obs, 0.25),2), 
            AUCinf75 = round(quantile(AUCINF_obs, 0.75),2),
            Cmax_25 = round(quantile(Cmax, 0.25), 2), 
            Cmax_75 = round(quantile(Cmax, 0.75), 2), 
            Cmax = round(median(Cmax), 2)) -> NCA.by.Dose.25_75tile

NCA.by.Dose.25_75tile
```

Comment: Thanks for a concise (and kind) correction to my stupid mistake, and for the pointer to dplyr.